# Django NoReverseMatch in form redirect

Tags: python, regex, django

I am getting the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /lld/new/

Reverse for 'display_lld' with arguments '()' and 
keyword arguments '{'slug': u'stack-overflow-new-document'}' not found.
0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I can't get to the bottom of it, though I think it has something to do with either my url regex or the `document.slug` variable passed to the `index.html` template in `views.py`.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect

from .models import Document
from .forms import DocumentForm


def index(request):
    document_list = Document.objects.order_by('-date_updated')
    context = {'document_list': document_list}
    return render(request, 'lld/index.html', context)


def display_lld(request, slug):
    document = get_object_or_404(Document, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'lld/display_lld.html', {'document': document})


def new_lld(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.save()
            return redirect('display_lld', slug=document.slug)
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'lld/new_lld.html', {'form': form})
```

site urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^lld/', include('lld.urls', namespace="lld")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # example: /lld/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # example: /lld/new/
    url(r'^new/$', views.new_lld, name='new_lld'),
    # ex: /lld/customername-projectname/
    url(r'^(?P<slug>([\w-]+))/', views.display_lld, name='display_lld'),
]
```

index.html:

```
{% if document_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for document in document_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'lld:display_lld' document.slug %}">{{ document.customer }} / {{ document.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No documents are available.</p>
{% endif %}
<a href="{% url 'lld:new_lld' %}">Create New LLD</a>
```

The form creates the new document fine, it shows up in the admin.  But when I click on the forms save button it brings up the `NoReverseMatch` error rather than redirecting back to the created document. The newly created document is listed on the index page and I can navigate to it by clicking on it's link there, it just appears to throw the error in the form redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `redirect`, you have left out the `lld` namespace. You need to include the namespace when you use `redirect` or `reverse`, the same way as you already do when you use the `{% url %}` tag in your templates:

```
return redirect('lld:display_lld', slug=document.slug)
```

Comment: Thankyou, I knew it would be something simple! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

return redirect(reverse('lld:display_lld', args=[document.slug]))
```